# How to extends Spring Data JPA @Query Method Annotation

Tags: spring, jpa, annotations, customization, spring-data-jpa

How to extends Spring Data JPA @Query Method Annotation ?

From this article http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/hibernate-native-sql-features-into-your.html I learn how to extends Spring data JPA Functionality, unfortunately the article tells about ElementType.TYPE annotation, but I need to understand ElementType.METHOD annotation and how this annotated method will by registered and handled by spring data jpa.

11052012 1547 --
I did further research about how to handle method annotation, I Found that I Need to involve AOP to intercept original method invocation with my custom annotation processor.

I Did this

```
@NoRepositoryBean
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Dynaque {
    String value() default "";
}


@NoRepositoryBean
@Aspect
@Component("dynaqueAopListener")
public class DynaqueAopListener {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(my.repo.engine.package.Dynaque)")
    public void dynaqueMethods() {
    }

    @Around("dynaqueMethods()")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Method m = ((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod();
        Dynaque d = null;
        if (m != null) {
            d = m.getAnnotation(Dynaque.class);

        }
        Object output = pjp.proceed();
        //my custom query logic here
        return output;
    }

}
```

Then I got next obstacle, 
I Found that SD JPA scan all methods of every Repository Interface and do QueryLookup using QueryLookupStrategy to them, I don't know how to exclude methods that using @Dynaque annotation from SD - JPA QueryLookup so that I can implement my own query logic to that methods.

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you elaborate? Do you want to know how '@NamedNativeQueries' could be used at method level? Or do you want to know how the '@Query' annotation works?

Comment: First, sorry for my bad English. Second, yes i wanted to know how 'Something like @NamedNativeQueries could be used at method level', basically I want to user my own method annotation.